# Qt Quick QML Customize ComboBox Popup

Tags: qt, combobox, qml, qtquick2

I am trying to customize the QML 2.14 ComboBox.
I did follow the below link but I am not able to customize the ComboBox -> Popup -> ListView -> "delegate"
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-combobox

I want to have diffrent Text Color for the list item displayed inside the ComboBox Popup.

```
ComboBox {
   id: myComboBox
   model: ["First", "Second", "Third"]

   popup: Popup {
      y: myComboBox.height - 1
      width: parent.width
      implicitHeight: contentItem.implicitHeight
 
      contentItem: ListView {
          clip: true
          anchors.fill: parent
          model: myComboBox.popup.visible ? myComboBox.delegateModel : null
          ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator {}

          delegate: Text {
              width: parent.width
              height: 30
              text: "Test" // How to access flat model, modelData is null and model.get(index) is not allowed in .ui.qml  
              color: "#ffffff"
              anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
              anchors.left: parent.left
          }

          highlight: Rectangle { color: "yellow" } 
      }
   }
}
```

But I always see some default list with black text, in the combobox popup.
Also not able to apply the highlight to selected line in the popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Combobox's model is a [DelegateModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-delegatemodel.html). That means the delegate is attached to the model. So trying to set the ListView's delegate will not have any effect. But the Combobox has its own `delegate` property that you can set.

```
ComboBox {
    delegate: Text {
        width: parent.width
        height: 30
        text: modelData
        color: "#ffffff"
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    }
}
```